# how to get the status (on/off/lock) of the monitor of a remote host

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, monitors

I login to a remote ubuntu host by ssh. Is there any command that can check if the monitor of the remote host is power-on/off or locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can
use [ddcutil](https://www.ddcutil.com) to check if the given
monitor is turned on by checking if value of VCP 0xd6 code is set to
anything else than 0x05 as specified in table 8-5 of the [VESA Monitor
Control Command
Set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/superduper/BrightnessMenulet/master/BrightnessMenulet/mccsV3.pdf):

```
$ sudo ddcutil -d 1 getvcp d6 |& awk '{ print $NF }'
(sl=0x01)
```

That means that the first display is turned on.

```
$ sudo ddcutil -d 1 getvcp d6 |& awk '{ print $NF }'
(sl=0x05)
```

That means that the first display is turned off.